# How do I check text C#

Tags: c#-4.0

How do I check the text in my textbox.

For example. My textbox contains: 31283712031720

I want to check the number 31 first then 28 then 37 etc. Like bit by bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do the numbers not have spaces or commas between them? Smells like bad design.

Answer (score 3):

Just get the text of the textbox and for-loop through by two characters each.

E.g.

```
String text = <get text of textbox here>

for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i += 2)
{
    string bit = text.Substring(i, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fristNumber = MyTexBox.Text[0] + MyTextBox.Text[1];
```

you could put it in a loop if you'd like